# How to get Python Pillow (PIL) version?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to get the [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) (Python Imaging Library) version installed on a Mac OS X computer. I've previously installed [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow), a more friendly fork of PIL.

I've tried:

```
import PIL
print('PIL',PIL.__version__)
```

And I've got the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: This question and answer have nothing specifically to do wtih Mac OS X, it would be nice to simply remove that from the title, it throws people off searching for this question on google.

Answer (score 21):

Use `PIL.__version__` or `Image.__version__`.

Before [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) version 6.0.0, its version string could be accessed via the following variable names:

```
>>> PIL.version.__version__
'5.1.0'
>>> PIL.PILLOW_VERSION
'5.1.0'
>>> PIL.__version__
'5.1.0'
>>>
```

Not to be confused with the last PIL version that Pillow is built on (and thus hangs on to):

```
>>> PIL.VERSION
'1.1.7'
```

There was no information on this in the documentation regarding the fork from PIL: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/about.html#why-a-fork

However, [PIL's homepage](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) states

> Status
> The current free version is PIL 1.1.7. This release supports Python 1.5.2 >and newer, including 2.5 and 2.6. A version for 3.X will be released later.

That release is dated "November 15, 2009".

This confirms it's just PIL's last release version.

---

For future/further digging:

The version string is defined in these source files: [`https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/version.py`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/version.py) and [`https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/__init__.py), or [search for all occurences of `__version__`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/search?q=__version__) in the repository.

(On my Windows, this is installed to `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PIL\version.py`)

---

**Update**

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/5.2.0.html

> 5.2.0 API Changes Deprecations
>
> These version constants have been deprecated. `VERSION` will be removed
> in Pillow 6.0.0, and `PILLOW_VERSION` will be removed after that.
>
> ```
> `PIL.VERSION` (old PIL version 1.1.7)
> `PIL.PILLOW_VERSION`
> `PIL.Image.VERSION`
> `PIL.Image.PILLOW_VERSION`
> ```
>
> Use `PIL.__version__` instead.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/6.0.0.html

> 6.0.0 Backwards Incompatible Changes
>
> Removed deprecated VERSION
>
> `VERSION` (the old PIL version, always 1.1.7) has been removed. Use
> `__version__` instead.

---

2021-12 - this answer is still correct:

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.__version__
'8.4.0'
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image.__version__
'8.4.0'
>>> Image.__version__ is PIL.__version__
True
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the version for PIL do

```
>>> PIL.VERSION
'1.1.7'
```

#### Edit:

This gives you only the PIL version not the Pillow version.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722022/4095334) answer for more detail.

Comment: Thanks! I've found another solution but yours is working fine too!

Comment: Note that this only returns the last version string of `PIL`, which `pillow` is based on (but they kept the module name).

Comment: To clarify: this does not return the version of Pillow.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found a solution:

```
from PIL import Image 
print('PIL',Image.VERSION)
```

Comment: This does not return the Version of Pillow, but the (old) underlying PIL version. It is identical to `PIL.VERSION` ([source](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L27)).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above answers, nothing worked for me, but this did (for version 8.0.1:

```
from PIL import Image
dir(Image)
# AH HAH!  there is an attribute __version__
print(Image.__version__)
```

8.0.1