# UnidentifiedImageError in imageclassification using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to tensorflow. I'm following the official tensorflow documentation where they have a sample project. which I'm executing.

[documentation link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#predict_on_new_data)

everything seem to be working fine but when I try to execute the last block where we are giving our model to identify what kind of flower it is.

here is the code

```
sunflower_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/592px-Red_sunflower.jpg"
sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Red_sunflower', origin=sunflower_url)

img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    sunflower_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

print(
    "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
)
```

the error is

```
    UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-a846503021fd> in <module>
      2 sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Red_sunflower', origin=sunflower_url)
      3 
----> 4 img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
      5     sunflower_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
      6 )

c:\users\amanpreet singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    293       ValueError: if interpolation method is not supported.
    294   """
--> 295   return image.load_img(path, grayscale=grayscale, color_mode=color_mode,
    296                         target_size=target_size, interpolation=interpolation)
    297 

c:\users\amanpreet singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
    113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
--> 114         img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115         if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    116             # if image is not already an 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit grayscale image

c:\users\amanpreet singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   2965     for message in accept_warnings:
   2966         warnings.warn(message)
-> 2967     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
   2968         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   2969     )

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000028FEBC63EF0>
```

how to resolve this error or another way to give my model images to predict??

Comment: Which version of PIL do you use? use this link to find out version of PIL that is already installed on your PC. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739775/how-to-get-python-pillow-pil-version

Comment: it is PIL 8.2.0

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Kaveh, the error is from PIL package.

The given Tensorflow [documentation link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#predict_on_new_data) supports PIL version 7.1.2.
Downgrade your PIL version

Comment: can you suggest a solution to how I can execute it using my PIL version because if I try to downgrade I need to install and set up everything again.

Comment: It is difficult to execute with current PIL version. Since Tensorflow dependencies causes error. Thanks!